# Please, explain this problem to me, I got lost at the step where they turned the denominator into 1

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hKIU.png)

I'm sorry I just don't understand this question, and I can't quite figure out why you would swap the denominator to the numerator, then make the denominator a 1.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @CenrealDeity: **Hint:** Multiply the numerator and denominator by $$\left(\sin \dfrac{x}{2} + i \cos \dfrac{x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me understand why it turned the denominator into 1, but why would we multiply the top, and the bottom in the first place?

Comment: When we have large and ugly expressions and there is an opportunity to beautify them, we rejoice! Look how we localized the imaginary terms in this ugly expression.

Comment: Is there a logic on why we do this, besides the fact that it would make the expression become much more manage-able?

Comment: You typically do not need to carry imaginary values in numerators and denominators.

Comment: So we'd just cancel them out, by multiplying them with a value that would cancel them out?

Comment: Look up Complex Conjugate and see: http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/sigma%20complex%20number%20leaflets/sigma-complex6-2009-1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In general, for $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ with $a^2+b^2>0$, we have
$$\frac{1}{a-ib} = \frac{a+ib}{(a+ib)(a-ib)} = \frac{a+ib}{a^2+b^2}.$$
This formula serves to make a complex denominator real.  If we rewrite this equation using $z\in \Bbb{C}$, we get a more compact version.
$$\frac1z = \frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2} \quad\forall\,z\in\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$$
Applying this formula to $z = \sin\dfrac{x}2 + i\cos\dfrac{x}2$ answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: @CentralDeity I'll be more grateful if you can learn to write in [MathJax](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020)

Answer (score 1):

They are multiplying the top and the bottom of the fraction conjugate of $$ sin (x/2) -i cos(x/2)$$ which is    $$ sin(x/2) +i cos(x/2)$$

What happened here is that the denominator simplified to $1$ because $$ (sin ( x/2) -i cos(x/2))((sin (x/2) -i cos(x/2)) = sin^2 (x/2) + cos^2(x/2)=1$$

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but how would sin^2(x/2) + cos^2(x/2) = 1? I am sorry, I'm not very good at Math.

Comment: Learn Trig Identities: https://www.symbolab.com/cheat-sheets/Trigonometry# . For your specific case, see the proof here: https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/how-prove-identiry-sin-2x-cos-2x-1-44233

Comment: @CentralDeity This is a trig identity. $ sin^2 (\alpha )+cos^2 (\alpha )=1$ for any $ \alpha$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @CentralDeity You are most welcome